# Use react-navigation without header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is there a way to tell the react-navigation library that I don't want to use headers in all the screens in my app?

Rather than setting navigationOptions = {
  header: null,
} in every single screen, is there some navigator level setting I could set just once?

Comment: I think it's not possible, because when you create new screen in `StackNavigation` you need to tell the screen that you don't want to show the header for the screen itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide header in stack navigator React navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701245/hide-header-in-stack-navigator-react-navigation)

Comment: Check out the above linked possible duplicate for an up to date solution, or go to https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headershown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set it as null on the navigationOptions like so:

```
export const StackRouter = StackNavigator({

  Screen1: {
    screen: Screen1,
  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2,
  },
  Screen3: {
    screen: Screen3,
  },
  Screen4: {
    screen: Screen4,
  }
},
{
  headerMode: 'float',
  navigationOptions:({navigation}) => ({
    header: null,
  }),

});
```

Answer (score 7):

This is the way which help you modify the header of React Navigation.

```
    export default createStackNavigator({
     Home: {
       screen: HomeScreen
     },
     Login: {
       screen: LoginScreen
    }
   },
  {
   initialRouteName: 'Home',
   mode: 'modal',
   headerMode: 'none'
  })
```

Look at the code, you can see it has a object to configure everything you want in React Navigation.

Check [this link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html) out for understanding it.!

Cheer!

Answer (score 0):

You have an option to hide the navigation area in all screen. Update your code like this.

```
export const Root = StackNavigator({
      Login: {
        screen: Home,
      },
    },{
      mode: 'modal',
      navigationOptions: {
             header: null//Will hide header for all screens of current stack navigator, 
       },
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply all screens of a stack you don't want to show header, just do this.

```
export const stackScreens = StackNavigator(
{ 
   Screen1: { screen: Screen1 },
   Screen2: { screen: Screen2 }
}, 
{ 
   navigationOptions : ({ navigation }) => ({
     header: null
   })
});
```