# How to hide header in react navigation?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to hide the header in the React-native app.
As far as I know, there are several ways to hide header in stack navigator.

```
const NavigatorsContainer = createStackNavigator({
  App: {
    screen: BottomTabStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false
    }
  },
  General: {
    screen: GeneralStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false
    }
  }
})
```

Then which case can I use the following method?

```
  General: {
    screen: GeneralStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
      //header: null,          //-- ?
      //headerMode: 'none',    //-- ?
      //headerVisible: 'none'  //-- ?
    }
  }
```

What is the difference between each other?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44701363/13457870
checkout this answer

Answer (score 0):

To disable header for a particular screen, (I suppose `GeneralStack` in your case), use this in that particular screen component `.js` file!

```
GeneralStack.navigationOptions=()=>{
    return {
        header:()=>null
    };
};
```