# Remove header on createMaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

how do I remove the header on createMaterialTopTabNavigator()?
I've looked everywhere, including the documentation. So far I've only seen examples
which are relevant to the previous version.

Here's my code:

```
<NavigationContainer headerMode='none'>
<Tab.Navigator options={{ headerShown: false }}>
<Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
<Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings}/>
</Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide header in stack navigator React navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701245/hide-header-in-stack-navigator-react-navigation)

Comment: @MuhammadIqbal unfortunately not... those seem to apply only to Stack, my issue is with Tab

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

HeaderShown option is for screens, not navigator. So replace by this

```
const IndexStack = createStackNavigator()

const index = () => {
    return(
        <IndexStack.Navigator initialRouteName="tabNav">
            <IndexStack.Screen name="tabNav" options={{ headerShown: false }}  component={tabNav} />
        </IndexStack.Navigator>
    )
}

const tabNav = () => {
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator>
                <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

Comment: My bad! The headers never went away

Comment: RN didn't like the nesting... I think I might have to work on the method.

Comment: Didn't like ? For big app you don't have choice. When you have multiple stacks, drawer, tabs etc it's the good way. RN doc make it like this

Comment: There's no "magical" code, it's a line of thought who works. I you have problems with react, follow tutorials before start a project