# React Navigation header not hiding

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a react project and I have two navigators, I'm trying to remove the navigation bar, I tried two ways but no success.
This is my App.js

```
const switchNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  loginFlow: createStackNavigator({
    Signin: {
      screen: SigninScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerShown: 'false'
      }
    },
    Signup: {
      screen: SignupScreen,
    },
  },
  ),
  mainGrid: createStackNavigator({
    Account: AccountScreen,
    Bath: BathScreen,
    Eco: EcoBath,
    Electricity: ElectricityConsScreen,
    Water: WaterConsumptionScreen,
    Help: HelpScreen,
    Parents: ParentsControlScreen
  })
});
```

As you can see I tried o hide using the headerShown: 'false' I tried to change to 'hide' and doesn't seems to work. I tried to add separately like:

```
SigninScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
    return{ 
        header: () => false
    };
};
```

But didn't worked too.
I tried to remove the arrow function and set like header: null and no success too.
What can I do about this?

Comment: which version of react natigation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide header in stack navigator React navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701245/hide-header-in-stack-navigator-react-navigation)

Comment: React Navigation 4.4.0

Comment: but your code does not look like V5, it looks like V3 or V4

Comment: The Stack cut the top part of my code.

Comment: but V5 uses <Stack.Screen /> not  "name: {  screen: ScreenName}"

Comment: You're right I checked now it's V4.4.0. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: if you have multiple nested stackNavigator then use navigationOptions: { header: null }, for all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are `using react-navigation V5`:

```
<Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="route-name" component={ScreenComponent} />
```

`else`:

hide header for 1 screen:

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator ({
    Home: {
        screen: HomePage, 
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
        },
    },
})
```

or

```
export default class HomePage extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    }
}
```

hide header for all screens:

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator ({
    Home: {
        screen: HomePage,
    },
},
{
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
    },
})
```

> Deprecation in 'navigationOptions': - 'header: null' will be removed
> in a future version. Use 'headerShown: false' instead

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator ({
    Home: {
        screen: HomePage, 
        navigationOptions: {
            headerShown: false
        },
    },
})
```

Comment: Tried all of these and didn't worked. I used these codes in my older projects and worked but it was just one navigator.

Comment: if you are using V5 then first solution should work, check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using following in my code:

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator ({
    Home: HomePageScreen
},
{
   headerMode: "none"
});
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headermode

Answer (score 0):

Mates I solved! I was using the Navigation v4.
The problem was here

```
const switchNavigator = createStackNavigator({
```

Then I swapped t

```
const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
```

And Added

```
SigninScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
    return {
      header: false
    };
};
```

Now It's working like a charm, but all answers that you lads answered are correct. I used in the other versions. Thanks for your time lads.