# How do I hide the header in react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Everything online has told me I have to do `headerShown: false` in order to hide the header but for some reason it is not working for me in my code:

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
   <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator 
         screenOptions={{
             headerShown: false
         }}>
            <Stack.Screen name='Welcome Screen' component={WelcomeScreen}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

I have done everything it said to do in the documentation but I am still seeing the header in the emulator.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701245/hide-header-in-stack-navigator-react-navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701245/hide-header-in-stack-navigator-react-navigation)

Comment: @ferter3006 I have done the solution for that post as you can see in my code but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one screen in your Stack Navigator, instead of hiding the header for the whole stack, hide it for the individual screen by using the Stack Screen option `headerShown` ->  `<Stack.Screen name='Welcome Screen' options={{headerShown: false}} component={WelcomeScreen}/>`.

Also, check if you are hiding the header in your welcome Screen, that might cause an issue and won't let you hide the header.